# How to generate array dynamically inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can create array inside an array .For example suppose **MainArray[]** is the one I have defined and based on some conditions like

```
if(something happen){
then push object into array inside MainArray
In other iteration make new array and push elements into that inside 
MainArray
}
```

Hope you get the question .Any kind of help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is what you are looking for:

```
// pushes an array at the end of MainArray
MainArray.push([]); 
// pushes elements into that newly created array inside MainArray
MainArray[MainArray.length-1].push('whatever u want...');
```

Comment: Thanks dude...that what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Pushing into an array inside another array is no different from pushing into any array.
Suppose you have an array `arr`

```
let arr = [[1],[2]];

arr[0].push(3);

console.log(arr)//[[1,3],[2]];
```

According to the comment, you'd want `[ [{},{}], [{}], [{},{},{}] ]`.
Let's assume we start with that.
If you do `arr[0].push({hello:"World"});` you will get
`[ [{},{},{hello:"World"}], [{}], [{},{},{}] ]`

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't expressed my question correctly . You have taken example of an 2D array but what if I want like [ [{},{}], [{}], [{},{},{}] ]

Comment: In your comment, what you want is basically a 2-D array. It's just an array of arrays containing objects.

Comment: That's why I apologize for not expressing my question in right way. If you get it now please help.Thank you

Comment: I know how to push and how it work. I just want to know without declaring 2d or any dimensional array can i push new array into it so that I can push new object into new array.

Comment: Yeah. Even without declaring any array, you can push other arrays into existing arrays. Or create new arrays and push arrays into the newly created arrays. I'm really struggling to figure out where it is exactly that you have a problem.